# Generate Less Source map with Play Framework 2

Tags: css, playframework-2.0, less, google-chrome-devtools

I saw that Play! 2 allowed the creation of source maps for coffeeScript. But what about Less ? I didn't find any resources on that.

It would be much appreciated in order to handle live modification with Chrome DevTools for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are completely overhauling the coffeescript, less and requirejs functionality for 2.3. We will be providing support for source maps across the board.

Comment: Good to know ! When is it scheduled ? Thanks ;)